# CORS policy issue with GKE ingress

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, google-cloud-load-balancer

We are facing an error related of CORS policy:

Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Is there any way to allow it from gce-ingress annotations ?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot currently be done using annotations.  The only option available is to modify the HTTP load balancer created by gce-ingress.  You can [set custom response headers](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/custom-headers#working-with-response) on the actual LB.  The variable `origin_request_header` can be used as the value of the `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Comment: I have tried to add custom header response but there isn't change in response error: 


Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "{origin_request_header}"
Origin-Request-Header: "*"
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: "true"
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS"

Please check the above details and let us know If we are doing something wrong in their writing format ?